# How to handle when array has two value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

with the following I am able to find each single value and remove class from it, but I wanted to add another condition where if array two value is there then do something, can somebody please review and give an idea

```
$.each($target, function(index, htmlEle) {
    if ($(htmlEle).data("testest") != undefined) {
        var arr = $(htmlEle).data("testest").split(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == value) {
                $(htmlEle).removeClass("hide");
            } else(arr[i] == value) {

            }

        }
    }

});
```

**EDIT:** Currently the output is, its finding one value and removing a class from it, what I want is, if 2 values are there then add Class.

Comment: `where if array two value is there then do something,`-> please describe it?

Comment: updated above, pls check

Comment: can you show us sample data of `arr`? then question will be more clear. add that in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the occurences of a value in an array like this:

```
 arr.reduce((count, el) => count + (el === value), 0)
```

You could then use it in a switch:

```
 const occurences = arr.reduce((count, el) => count + (el === value), 0);

 switch(occurences) {
   case 1:
    alert("one");
   case 2:
    alert("two");
}
```